# How to avoid memory leak? (In this example and in general)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gtk3

Following is the code snippet:

```
g_autofree gchar *foo = NULL;
foo = "Hello";
foo = g_strconcat (line, "there", NULL);
```

Is there a memory leak of the previous ref of foo? Why?
How to avoid such memory leaks?

Any other tips also welcome!

Comment: You can use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect any memory leak.

Comment: String literals are not stored in dynamic/heap memory. So it can't be freed (except when the whole application exits) and hence there is no memory leak.

Comment: You have a memory leak if you code: `foo = g_strconcat (line, "there", NULL)` `foo = g_strconcat (line, "is", NULL)` You are creating/allocating `"is"` without call `g_free` to free the previous allocated `"there" `

Comment: Leaks etc. are avoided by not writing bad code.

Comment: @LPs How would u avoid a leak in the example that you've given?

Comment: In the same way @MartinJames wrote ;) There are no standard mechanisms to avoid those kind of problems. Only write a good code. So each time you use a `malloc` like function you have to think twice to the pointer you are using and if needs a `free` before to be overwriteen.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, your string literal should be a `const char *` since it's undefined behaviour to modify a pointer to a string literal. Making it constant isn't required in C, but this would be more correct:

```
g_autofree char *foo = NULL;
const char *bar = "Hello";
foo = g_strconcat(bar, "there", NULL);
```

If you internalize the rule to always give pointers to string literals a `const char *` type, and never free `const char *` variables, then the above code will eventually instinctively look less wrong.

As for the general case, there is no better answer than "don't overwrite a heap-allocated pointer unless you've freed it." Again, given enough experience writing C, doing so will instinctively look wrong.